# Angular Material md-card and Flex Layout not filling screen

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

I am trying to get a card component to do a 100% height, i must be doing something wrong. I have tried setting globally in scss, locally in component, inline, every flex layout combination i could think of to achieve this. Show me the way ancient kung fu masters!

[image]

```
<div class="container" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
  <div class="container" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center stretch">
    <md-card fxFlex='99'>
        <div class="navigation">
            <nav md-tab-nav-bar>
                <a md-tab-link *ngFor="let link of navigationLinks" [routerLink]="[link]" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" [active]="rla.isActive">
            {{link}}
            </a>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your  elements are not opened and closed properly (you have 2 opening s on the top and only one closing at the bottom).
Second, please provide plunker so others could see and understand what you are trying to achieve. 
As for now it's not clear what 100% height you are talking about.  will take only as much space as it required to display content. It will grow as long as you add content. If you want it to be bigger you need to specify fixed height value.